# Symfony 2.1 Autologin after facebook login

Tags: facebook, authentication, symfony-2.1, facebook-login, autologin

I'm creating an intranet, therefore all users have account automatically created for them. They then go to a url to create their password.  All that works great.  I'm now trying to allow them to "attach" their Facebook account to their user account.  This is where my troubles have started...

I've successfully gotten the user to authenticate properly after a facebook login with this 
method in `SecurityController`

```cs
public function loginCheckFacebookAction()
{

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();
    $response = new Response();


    $sessionUser = $this->getUser();

    $facebook = $this->get('facebook');

    $fbUser = $facebook->getUser(); // facebook id


    if ($fbUser) {
      try {

          $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
          $repo = $em->getRepository("IntranetBundle:User");
          $user = $repo->findUserByFBID($fbUser);


          if($user){

              $targetPath = $session->get("_target_path");

               $firewall = "secured_area";

               $roles = $user->getRoles();

               $rolesArray = array();

    foreach($roles as $role):
        $rolesArray[] = $role->getRole();
    endforeach;

               $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), $firewall, $rolesArray);

               $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($this->getRequest(), $token);
               $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

               $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);


              /*
              If I uncomment out either of the following redirects
              the redirect happens but the user is not authenticated properly
              If I comment them out I'm just rendering my error template.  The user
              however, is authenticated properly.
              */  
              if(isset($targetPath)){
                  //return $this->redirect($targetPath);
              } else {
                  //return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("ssla_intranet_homepage"));
              }


          }

      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

          $user = null;

      }

    // I just render this template to be able to view debug bar.  
    //User is authenticated properly.

    $pageParameters = $this->getPageParameters();
    $pageParameters["page"] = "error";
    $pageParameters["error"] = array();
    $pageParameters["error"]["message"] = "Something went wrong with authentication";

    return $this->render('IntranetBundle:Error:index.html.twig', $pageParameters);
}
```

Do I need to register a listener for all `interactive_login` events that then handles all `post-login` redirection rather than trying to redirect within the same method?

First project using Symfony, and this is killing me. Any thoughts?

By the way, I've looked into the **FOSFacebookBundle**, but wanted to be able to authenticate with a number of different methods, including doctrine, gmail, facebook, and twitter.

Comment: This is a great way to implement FB login with symfony. God job.